# send data internet using C

Tags: c

I need to send a signal via my remote PC to the Internet that let me know if this pc is connected.
I could send a link with GET values to my page and then from that php page make a query to the database.
How do I send this value through a C program that runs on this remote PC?
thanks!

(it's a windows pc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For making HTTP requests I recommend libcurl, which is the library that almost everybody seems to be using.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Comment: with devc++ i have problems in include library files. what is a better c compiler? thanks

Comment: I keep hearing devc++ is old and abandoned, people recommend code::blocks or similar.  You can also download free Express versions of MSVC. (free as in beer)

Answer (score 1):

What operating system? Linux? Windows? Does the program need to be cross-platform? The reason I ask is that it influences whether you should use a library, or TCP/IP sockets, given that the request will be very simple.

Also, why not use Perl, or better yet, wget? You could schedule a task in windows, or a cronjob in unix, to `` wget http://yoururl/path?pcname=`uname` `` or similar..

Comment: it is windows, I could use sockets?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a client like [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/)? I'm not sure using a C program would be such a good idea for that purpose; it's a system administration task and using scripting for this would work best, unless you have a specific need in mind.